# Applying a class specially to the badge

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using Ionic/Angular and also [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to give some fancy touches.

At first I was using this type of tabs and everything was working properly

```
<a class="tab-item has-badge" href="#/app/bet-slip">
  <span class="badge badge-assertive animated"
        ng-class="picksCount?'rubberBand':'bounceIn'">{{betSlipCount}}</span>
  <i class="icon ion-code-download"></i>
</a>
```

but the requirements says that I need to use `<ion-tabs></ion-tabs>` and thats what I am trying.

In the first type of tabs above you can see that there is a `<span>` that actually holds a badge with an `ng-class` and at the end `{{betSlipCount}}`, that `ng-class` it is been applied every time that `{{betSlipCount}}` which is an integer changes thru a boolean named `picksCount`. now I am using the type of tabs I mentioned before and now I have:

```
<ion-tab title="BetSlip"
         class="animated"
         ng-class="picksCount?'rubberBand':'bounceIn'"
         badge="betSlipCount"
         badge-style="badge-assertive">

        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>

</ion-tab>
```

as you can see some stuff change there, the badege now is inside the same first tap I do not know how to apply the `ng-class` correctly in this case, and I need the same behavior, I need that class applied to the badge every time that the `betSlipCount` changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the ng-class condition there at all. That condition should be in your controller and just store the calculated class in your controller and use that variable in your ng-class statement in the html. The value change should be automatically updated in the html when that scope variable changes. 
Haven't tried, but it might solve the issue.